# Multiple one-to-many relations in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need to express multiple one-to-many relations in Django. That is, given several different models, I need *each* of these to have a one-to-many relation with a single table. Logically, the relation belongs to the model "owning" the one-to-many relation, but Django forces me to use a many-to-one relation on the *target* table, instead of a one-to-many relation on the *source* table. Here's what I wish I could do:

```
class Sink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=24)

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=24)
    sink = models.ManyToOneField(Sink)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=24)
    sink = models.ManyToOneField(Sink)
```

but `ManyToOneField` doesn't exist. Instead, I'm supposed to use `ForeignKey` for *each* one-to-many field, like:

```
class Sink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=24)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=24)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=24)
```

which is logically just *wrong*, since there is never a case where I want both Sink.a and Sink.b to be non-null. If `ManyToManyField` allowed me to specify that it's not *really* many-to-many, I could do that, but it doesn't seem to allow that. What's the right way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) to link your Sink model to a single A or B model with a `GenericForeignKey`:

```
class Sink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=24)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=24)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=24)
```